# How can I pass this String obtained to jsonObject format?

Tags: java, json, mule-esb

Executing the code I get a String with the following value `"idStation=6107AAE80593E4B2&timestamp=1558524847&pm1=0.800&pm2_5=1.510&pm10=2.650&temperature=22.380&humidity=40.379&pressure=93926.656&luminosity=131&coC=0.440923810000&no2C=0.000000000000&o3C=8.210327100000&batteryLevel=27&batteryCurrent=0&baterryVolts=3.63"`

My goal is to convert that String into JsonObject format where each value is separated, that is, idstation = 6107AAE80593E4B2, etc., and to be able to continue treating the data later

the idea is to take for example the value of no2 and save it in a variable of type (Map String, Object)

```
eventPayload.put ("no2", String.valueOf (no2));
```

the value of the string is coded in the variable "sinCifrar"

I tried the following code, but I have problems:

```
'String jsonString = sinCifrar;
JSONObject jsonk = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            no2 = (((jsonk.getDouble("pressure")/101325.0)*(jsonk.getDouble("no2C")/1000)*46.0055)/(0.082*(jsonk.getDouble("temperature")+273.15)))*1000000.0;
            co = (((jsonk.getDouble("pressure")/101325.0)*(jsonk.getDouble("coC")/1000)*28.01)/(0.082*(jsonk.getDouble("temperature")+273.15)))*1000000.0;
            o3 = (((jsonk.getDouble("pressure")/101325.0)*(jsonk.getDouble("o3C")/1000)*48.0)/(0.082*(jsonk.getDouble("temperature")+273.15)))*1000000.0;'
```

I get the following error:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Since it is not a string created from the beginning, but it is obtained after executing several methods, I can not leave it with the requested format, any idea?

Comment: Read this article please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pablo Poli I have an answer posted below, let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is not a valid JSON but what you want , can be acheived using simple java code as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String test = "idStation=6107AAE80593E4B2&timestamp=1558524847&pm1=0.800&pm2_5=1.510&pm10=2.650&temperature=22.380"
            + "&humidity=40.379&pressure=93926.656&luminosity=131&coC=0.440923810000&no2C=0.000000000000&o3C=8.210327100000&"
            + "batteryLevel=27&batteryCurrent=0&baterryVolts=3.63";
    String[] result = test.split("&");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String string : result) {
        String[] str = string.split("=");
        map.put(str[0], str[1]);
    }
    double pressure = Double.valueOf(map.get("pressure"));
    double no2C = Double.valueOf(map.get("no2C"));
    double tempreture = Double.valueOf(map.get("temperature"));
    double o3C = Double.valueOf(map.get("o3C"));
    double cOC = Double.valueOf(map.get("coC"));
    System.out.println("Pressure:: "+pressure+" , no2c :: "+no2C+", tempreture:: "+tempreture+" ,o3C:: "+o3C+" ,coC:: "+cOC);
}
```

output

```
Pressure:: 93926.656 , no2c :: 0.0, tempreture:: 22.38 ,o3C:: 8.2103271 ,coC:: 0.44092381
```

From the map you can get any Key value you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have replaced your map <string, string> with Map <String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap <String, Object> (); so that I can then create a jsonObject: JSONObject jsonk = new JSONObject (map); and from there go saving the values ​​collected in another Map <String, Object> eventMap = new LinkedHashMap <String, Object> ();
after dealing with the values.

This way the code ends up working correctly, at least it gives me the sensation, tomorrow I will do the tests sending new data from a waspmote sensor and I confirm you